# Why was this answer deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation, link-only-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer to this question:

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11408216/ios5-storyboard-version-of-facebook-integration

The moderator comment was:

> Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

It's interesting since the accepted answer was basically what I had previously answered. I'm curious about why my answer was continually deleted when the answer was looking for a sample tutorial and a link was the best example. In the future, what's the best way to resolve this? At the time I decided to give up on answering the question as I didn't see any options.

Comment: **"we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer"** hm to me, this advice sounds simple enough. In my experience such answers are fairly easy to edit as requested ([1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/155445/revisions "example"), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/155331/revisions "example"), [3](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/146856/revisions "example"), [4](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/148431/revisions "example")...)

Comment: The answer is now undeleted. Next time, put a bit more effort in the answer. And all wil benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post was first only a link. And link only answers are subject to deletion.

The edited version looks better that the accepted answer, so either your answer needs to be undeleted or both must be deleted.

Only a moderator can undelete the post, so I have flagged it. You can do the same.

Comment: My edited version (on Sept 29) was also deleted by the moderator, so I left it alone. Things are clearer now and next time I'll know what to do.

Comment: @CAbernathy No, your answer was deleted *once*.  When you edit it, it doesn't automatically undelete it.  You have to have it undeleted.  The [post history](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/posts/12648942/revisions) clearly shows that the answer was deleted only once.